# How to prevent my empty strings from being part of the length

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Problem: I have input fields that should turn into green buttons when the correct `syllables` have been inserted. However the problem: it does so by the length of my JSON vs what the user has inserted, but when my array contains only 2 words instead of 4 it still requires a total of 4. For example: I have 2 words in my array and 2 empty strings in the array, I am forced to press enter twice to reach the length of the desired array. How can I make this that it will only check the length based on words in my array and not empty strings?

This is how one of my JSON files looks like:

```
{
 "main_object": {
"id": "5",
"getExerciseTitle": "TestFor",
"language": "nl_NL",
"application": "lettergrepen",
"main_object": {
  "title": "TestFor",
  "language": "nl_NL",
  "exercises": [
    {
      "word": "test",
      "syllables": [
        "test01",
        "test02",
        "test03",
        ""
      ]
    },
    {
      "word": "tesst",
      "syllables": [
        "test11",
        "test12",
        "",
        ""
      ]
    }
  ]
},
"dataType": "json"
 }
}
```

how the function has been created, don't mind the incremental counters etc. they are already declared.

```
function createExercise(json) {
const exercises = json.main_object.main_object.exercises;

var exerciseArea = $('<div/>', {
    id: 'exerciseField',
    'class': 'col-md-12'
});

$.map(exercises, function (exercise, i) {

    var exer = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'row form-group',
        'id': +idRow++
    })

    var colLeft = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'col-md-3'
    });

    var row = $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'row'
    });

    var audCol = $('<div>', {
        class: 'col-md-3 audioButton'
    }).append(getAudioForWords());

    var wordCol = $('<div>', {
        class: 'col-md-9 ExerciseWordFontSize exerciseWord',
        'id': 'wordInput[' + ID123 + ']', // note to self: the brackets will need to be escaped in later DOM queries
        text: exercise.word
    });
    row.append(audCol, wordCol);
    colLeft.append(row);

    var sylCol = $('<div>', {
        class: 'col-md-9'
    });

    var sylRow = $('<div/>', {
        class: 'row syll-row'
    });

    var correctSylls = [];

    $.map(exercise.syllables, function (syllable, j) {
        // Code to check if the syllable exists and is not an empty string
        if(!syllable){
            // If it doesn't exist or is an empty string, return early without creating/appending elements
            return;
        }
        var innerSylCol = $('<div/>', {
            class: 'col-md-3 inputSyllables'
        });

        var sylInput = $('<input/>', {
            'type': 'text',
            'class': 'form-control syl-input',
            'name':  +c++,
            'id': +idsyll++
        }).on('keyup', function() {
            var cValue = $(this).val();
            if (cValue === syllable) {
              correctSylls.push(cValue);
              console.log(correctSylls);
            }
            if (exercise.syllables.length === correctSylls.length) {
              $(this).closest('.syll-row').find('input.syl-input').addClass('btn btn-success').removeClass('form-control');
            }

        });

        innerSylCol.append(sylInput);
        sylRow.append(innerSylCol);
    });
    idsyll = 0;

    sylCol.append(sylRow);

    exer.append(colLeft, sylCol);

    exerciseArea.append(exer);
});
return exerciseArea;
}
```

The part what is causing the problem:

```
var correctSylls = [];

        var sylInput = $('<input/>', {
            'type': 'text',
            'class': 'form-control syl-input',
            'name':  +c++,
            'id': +idsyll++
        }).on('keyup', function() {
            var cValue = $(this).val();
            if (cValue === syllable) {
              correctSylls.push(cValue);
              console.log(correctSylls);
            }
            if (exercise.syllables.length === correctSylls.length) {
              $(this).closest('.syll-row').find('input.syl-input').addClass('btn btn-success').removeClass('form-control');
            }

        });
```

So I basically have 2 problems here: 1) It somehow is duplicating words in the array for no apparent reason? and 2) it still requires 4 words in my array (The empty strings are considered as a length too). but I don't empty strings to be considered as a length since they contain no words. The other question is: Why is it duplicating words in the array?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can filter the array to only return non empty items. Then loop over the filtered array in your map()

```js
var syllables = [
  "test11",
  "test12",
  "",
  ""
];

var filtered = syllables.filter(function(str) {
  return str.trim()
});

console.log(filtered)
```

Comment: Tried doing ur code, but it throws the error "str.trim is not a function". even when I do put it in a function

Comment: Using it wrong then. Can clearly see it works when you clcik on "run code snippet"

Comment: i'm sorry. I indeed tried again with a function, I had written function wrong, but could you elaborate why my string returns a duplicate of the words within my array? or is that something that cannot be detected based on the code I have?

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly

Comment: if u look at the picture in my post you see it has duplicate words in it. in the same array to be exact, but if you take a look at my JSON file you see no duplicate of words in a certain array. what is causing this ? or is this because I would press enter and therefore it would duplicate that word ?

Comment: not sure. Create a demo that reproduces it using a copy of part of file as source